# How do I know which node is focused in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a lot of `TextArea` nodes in a `Scene`.

Is it possible for me to figure out which `TextArea` is selected (has the caret in it)?
I would like to be able to select the node and set it to a `Node` variable.

Comment: Add a listener to it

Comment: When you select a `TextArea`, the JVM registers this. If you add an event listener to it, and make the listener perform an action (such as turning the background of the `TextArea` red), then you will know if it is selected or not. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I edited the question; I meant to ask if I can find a way to select the node and set it to a variable.

Comment: You mean like `if(thisNodeHasCaret) TextArea selectedNode = myTextArea;`?

Comment: Add in more code to your question regarding the TextArea and I'll submit an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually there is no need to set a focused node variable, because `Scene` already contains a `focusOwnerProperty`.

So you could use it e.g. like:

```
    if (scene.focusOwnerProperty().get() instanceof TextArea) {
        TextArea focusedTextArea = (TextArea) scene.focusOwnerProperty().get();
    }
```